# Cts Query from java client api is not giving proper search results

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I am trying to execute the below code from my application. But it is not giving me proper results. I am not sure, whether I am using proper handle and query definition in the code. Can someone please help me on this issue?

```
QueryManager queryManager = queryManager(ClientRole.GT_CONTRIBUTOR);
JSONDocumentManager docMgr = jsonDocumentManager(ClientRole.GT_CONTRIBUTOR);
CtsQueryBuilder ctsQueryBuilder = queryManager.newCtsSearchBuilder();
CtsQueryExpr ctsQueryExpr =
    ctsQueryBuilder.cts.pathRangeQuery(
        "/id",
        "=",
        "141433");
CtsQueryDefinition ctsQueryDefinition = ctsQueryBuilder.newCtsQueryDefinition(ctsQueryExpr);
JacksonHandle jacksonHandle = new JacksonHandle();
RawCombinedQueryDefinition rawQueryDef =
    queryManager.newRawCombinedQueryDefinition(new StringHandle( ctsQueryDefinition.serialize()).withFormat(Format.JSON));    rawQueryDef.setCollections(GuestTrackerConstants.SEGMENT_COLLECTION);
docMgr.setPageLength(1000);
DocumentPage docPage = docMgr.search(rawQueryDef, 1, jacksonHandle);
```

Comment: (1) What are you expecting?  and (2) what are the results.

Comment: Query after serialization : 

{
  "search": {
    "ctsast": {
      "ns": "cts",
      "fn": "path-range-query",
      "args": [
        {
          "ns": "xs",
          "fn": "string",
          "args": [
            "/id"
          ]
        },
        {
          "ns": "xs",
          "fn": "string",
          "args": [
            "="
          ]
        },
        {
          "ns": "xs",
          "fn": "string",
          "args": [
            "141433"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Comment: Below is the error I am getting,

Bad Request. Server Message: REST-INVALIDPARAM: (err:FOER0000) Invalid parameter: Invalid XML query structure (check namespace): <search:ctsast ns="cts" xmlns:search="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search"><search:fn>path-range-query</search:fn><search:args ns="xs"><search:fn>string</search:fn><search:args>/id</search:args></search:args><search:args ns="xs"><search:fn>string</search:fn><search:args>=</search:args></search:args><search:args ns="xs"><search:fn>string</search:fn><search:args>141433</search:args></search:args></search:ctsast>

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find StructuredQueryBuilder to be easier to use - try something like this:

```
QueryManager mgr = client.newQueryManager();
StructuredQueryBuilder queryBuilder = mgr.newStructuredQueryBuilder();
StructuredQueryBuilder.PathIndex index = queryBuilder.pathIndex("/properties/OBJECTID");
StructuredQueryDefinition query = queryBuilder.range(index, "xs:string", StructuredQueryBuilder.Operator.EQ, "11003");
JsonNode results = mgr.search(query, new JacksonHandle()).get();
System.out.println(results.toPrettyString());
```

You can easily add a collection via query.setCollections as well.

Edited - you mentioned you need to use CtsQueryExpr. Here's an example of getting that to work:

```
QueryManager queryManager = client.newQueryManager();
CtsQueryBuilder queryBuilder = queryManager.newCtsSearchBuilder();
CtsQueryExpr expr = queryBuilder.cts.pathRangeQuery("/properties/OBJECTID", "=", "11003");
CtsQueryDefinition queryDef = queryBuilder.newCtsQueryDefinition(expr);
JsonNode response = queryManager.search(queryDef, new JacksonHandle()).get();
System.out.println(response.toPrettyString());
```

Note that JacksonHandle will give you back a JsonNode. You can use StringHandle if you just need a String. You can also use SearchHandle to obtain a bunch of methods to get you access to data in the search response.

Comment: Here's a link for using StructuredQueryBuilder too - https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/searches#id_22570 .

Comment: Hi @rjrudin, I am dependent on cts query because to get a solution for the problem which I have posted in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75685201 can be achievable using cts.jsonPropertyScopeQuery but not by containerQuery as far as I have tried. So, If I get the solution for the link which I have mentioned before in  structured query itself then I can ignore the idea of using cts query.